# How to automatically update cloudwatch dashboard with metrics from CW agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I installed CW agent to get more metrics on some EC2 instances and then made a dashboard with these metrics. I need the dashboard to update automatically every week. New instances are launched when we do releases and we do not use auto-scaling groups.

I followed the guide here: 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/keeping-cloudwatch-dashboards-up-to-date-using-aws-lambda/

I am targeting EC2 instances with certain tags and tag values.

The lambda is getting triggered, however it is not updating my dashboard. Does the lambda provided by AWS update graphs where metrics are from CWAgent?

From the lambda logs I can see it is getting triggered but I get 
`INFO Dashboard Metrics is unchanged, update skipped`.

I can see the new instance is online and reporting metrics but the dashboard wont update. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see anything from the CWAgent? `cat /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log`

Comment: Can you share the cloudwatch widget json and verify that aws agent is running on your new instance?

Comment: Have you tried using a search expression? That way it'll get all the instances without having to update the dashboard over and over.